# multi head linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working with linked lists in c but my program needs actually a big number of linked lists at the same time and so when I want to add a new node I must determine to which list should I add, I have a function which return the head of the desired list to add but I am a little bit confused how should I write the "add_node" function because the head node is not the same every time and I don't want to use the "switch case" because it would be very long...
Thanks in advance

```
void add_it(int *array)
{
    head=which_head(array);
    curr = malloc(sizeof (node));
    memcpy(curr->nconn, array, sizeof (curr->nconn));
    curr->next = ?????????;
    ???????=curr
}
```

Comment: None of your variables have any types, except for `array`.

Comment: Why not keep all the linked lists together in an array and use the which_head function to determine which linked list to place the new node in the array? It'd be more like a hashmap with chaining though with the which_head being the hash function of some sort. Unless all the linked list are different than never mind my suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Node
{
    Node *next;
    int   myData[80];
};

Node **which_head(some params);

void Add(some data)
{
    Node **head_location = whitch_head(...);
    Node *new_element = (Node*)malloc(...);

    new_element->next = *head_location;
    *head_location = new_element;
}
```

The trick is that your `which_head()` function should return location of the head, not the pointer to the first element of the list if any.

Comment: thank you for your respose but I am a little bit new...
in my which_head the return is so : `return head24065;`
how should I edit it ?

Comment: It should be `return &head24065`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the linked list heads in an array or again in another linked list. I will tell you to keep the linked list functions general and should not have code to handle multiple lists. When you need to add some node to a particular linked list, you can fetch it using a function from the array/linked list and then use the returned head pointer to the general linked list functions. Thus you can keep the extra code for handling multi-head issue outside the linked list routines.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correctly, You want some linklists with having different headers for each. Now you want to access all linklists in a same manner.

My solution is Why did not you try `Hash Table`?

Try Hash Table and you will get solution.